# Hide image URL containing DB info

Tags: java, javascript, mysql, html

I've been having a little issue with image URLs. Usually I wouldn't care about hiding the URL since it shouldn't have any compromising information. But in this case, the URL has sensitive information regarding the MySQL DataBase.

Even if it is not very common and personally I don't think it's the best solution (it was like this already when i started using it and i cant change it), the images are stored in the DB entirely in a BLOB format. The image's URL format is as follows:

```
http://dbserverurl/servlets/java.packages.location?sTableName=table_name&KeyColumns=value
```

In this DBServer there is another web application running that seems to return the desired image with that info.

As you can see if I put the URL publicly it will create quite a huge security hole and that is by no means my purpose! I know I can send the blob images coded in base64 and show them directly in an img element, but I'm gonna handle quite a lot of images and I dont really think this is the best solution.

So, if anyone knows any way to hide/change/redirect the URL in some way, that'd awesome. I don't even know if its possible, but its worth a try.

Just so you know, MySQL database is accessed by a Java web application running on a tomcat server that then sends the image via XHR to a JavaScript function and then is displayed in the web page.

Comment: You could, though it has it's own problems, just map the query part with an arbitrary value (e.g. pk in a new mapping table) and use that in the image url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not pass safe URLs to the client and then use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/) on the server to fetch the resource?